# Failed to receive 200 ok Response on Android emulator from a local Flask server

Tags: android, localhost, retrofit, flask-restful

I've exposed simple APIs with Flask on my machine.
Server is running and serves correctly requests.

I am developing a Android app, that should consume these APIs.
I'm using Retrofit as client and I'm running the app in Android Emulator (API 28).

Well, the app sends the request to the server (I've used 10.0.2.2 as address), and the request is received by the server. It responds with 200 OK, but the call.enqueue method on my app calls onFailure() and I receive no response.

...

```
//API URL 
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://10.0.2.2:5002/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish);

    //REST Controls
    //Retrofit Instantiation
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    //Service to access APIs
    myServerInterface apiService =
            retrofit.create(myServerInterface.class);

    //Consume
    Call<List<NoiseMeasurement>> call = apiService.getNoiseMeasurements();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<NoiseMeasurement>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<NoiseMeasurement>> call, Response<List<NoiseMeasurement>> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            //adapter.addAll(response.body());
            Log.d("glt", "SUCCESS");
            Log.d("glt", response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<NoiseMeasurement>> call, Throwable t) {
            try {
                Log.d("glt", t.getCause().toString());
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.d("glt", "No connection available" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

...

I've tried to send the request via browser: it works fine! 
So why I receive no response? (NullPointerException is thrown on t.getCause().toString());
I've also tried to downgrade API to 26. Same result.

Comment: Maybe response is not matching given type `List<NoiseMeasurement>` and its failing during json to class conversion? I dont remember what error is thrown in that case :D

Comment: @Gralls thanks for answering. You were rigth. Server returned a single json object instead of a list. Sometimes simple problems seem to be huge! 

Thank you!